# Android - getting very big JSON array from web - cause crush

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-asynctask

I'm developing Android app which take very big JSON array from web server(by AsyncTask), sometimes its crushing and sometimes its not - I think it's because I'm reciving a huge json array (around  1500 JSON objects), also, when I'm getting around 250 JSON objects its working great.

the app taking the JSON array and adding it to LIstView with Custome adatper.

**On Create:**

```
try {
async_get_songs = new Read_today_songs();
async_get_songs.execute();
asynk_timeout(async_get_songs, 15000);
} catch (Exception e) {
    new Read_today_songs().execute();
}
```

**AsyncTask:**

```
public class Read_today_songs extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        boolean running = true;

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
            finish();
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                jsonArray = getJSONs_array();
                if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                    today_song_item = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // singerName = jsonObject.getString("singerName");
                        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        String singerName_coverted = jsonObject.getString("singerName").replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|' ')", "");
                        String songName_coverted = jsonObject.getString("songName").replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|' ')", "");
                        String date_coverted = jsonObject.getString("date").replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|' ')", "");

                        map.put("singerName", singerName_coverted);
                        map.put("songName", songName_coverted);
                        map.put("date", date_coverted);
                        today_song_item.add(map);
                    }
                    return "true";
                } else
                    return "false";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pbPlaylist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            etSearchPlaylist.setEnabled(true);
            // check if got the today_song_itemArrayList<Map<String, String>>()
            // with values
            if (result.contains("true")) {
                ArrayList<Song> mListItems = new ArrayList<Song>();
                for (Map<String, String> mapItem : today_song_item) {
                    Song song_item = new Song(mapItem.get("singerName"), mapItem.get("songName"), mapItem.get("date"));
                    mListItems.add(song_item);
                }

                mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(thePlayList.this, R.layout.playlist_item_layout, mListItems);
                lvSongsList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            } else
                fb_msg = "שגיאה התרחשה!";
        }
    }

public JSONArray getJSONs_array() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(current_url);
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
        HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
        int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (status == 200) {
            HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            JSONArray JSONarray = new JSONArray(data);
            return JSONarray;
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

**The CustomeAdatper:**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Song> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Song> mlist) {
        super(context, resource);
        dbTools = new DBTools(context);
        this.mlist = mlist;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition(Song item) {
        return super.getPosition(item);
    }

    @Override
    public Song getItem(int position) {
        return mlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playlist_item_layout, null);// Replace your                         // layout....
        tvArtist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvArtist);
        tvSongName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSongName);
        tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        ivFav = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivFav);

        tvArtist_from_list = mlist.get(position).getSingerName();
        tvSongName_from_list = mlist.get(position).getSongName();
        tvDate_from_list = mlist.get(position).getDate();

        tvArtist_from_list = tvArtist_from_list.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|' ')", "");
        tvSongName_from_list = tvSongName_from_list.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|' ')", "");
        tvDate_from_list = tvDate_from_list.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|' ')", "");

        tvArtist.setText(tvArtist_from_list);
        tvSongName.setText(tvSongName_from_list);
        tvDate.setText(tvDate_from_list);

        try {
            Cursor c = dbTools.getAllRowsByQuery("SELECT * FROM favs WHERE singerName='"+tvArtist_from_list+"' AND songName='"+tvSongName_from_list+"'");
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                ivFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.plank4);
                ivFav.setTag("full");
            }else{
                ivFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.plank4_empty);
                ivFav.setTag("");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            alert(e.toString());

        }
        return convertView;
    }
    // Filter Class
    public void filter(CharSequence cs) {
        String cs_string = String.valueOf(cs);
        cs_string = cs_string.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        if (original_mlist==null) {
            original_mlist = new ArrayList<Song>();
            original_mlist.addAll(mlist);
        }
        this.mlist.clear();
        if (cs_string.length() == 0) {
            mlist.addAll(original_mlist);

        } else {
            for (Song song_item : original_mlist) {
                if (son

g_item.getFullSongName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(cs_string) ||
                            song_item.getSingerName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(cs_string) ||
                            song_item

.getDate().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(cs_string)) {
                        this.mlist.add(song_item);
                    }
                }
            }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            public void alert(String get_fb_msg) {
                Toast.makeText(context, get_fb_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    }
```

**the console error:**

```
04-01 18:49:50.082: E/AndroidRuntime(31326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 18:49:50.082: E/AndroidRuntime(31326): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 18:49:50.082: E/AndroidRuntime(31326):    at com.manishma.thePlayList$Read_today_songs.onPostExecute(thePlayList.java:383)
04-01 18:49:50.082: E/AndroidRuntime(31326):    at com.manishma.thePlayList$Read_today_songs.onPostExecute(thePlayList.java:1)
04-01 18:49:50.082: E/AndroidRuntime(31326):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-01 18:49:50.082: E/AndroidRuntime(31326):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-01 18:49:50.082: E/AndroidRuntime(31326):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-01 18:49:50.082: E/AndroidRuntime(31326):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 18:49:50.082: E/AndroidRuntime(31326):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-01 18:49:50.082: E/AndroidRuntime(31326):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5171)
04-01 18:49:50.082: E/AndroidRuntime(31326):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 18:49:50.082: E/AndroidRuntime(31326):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-01 18:49:50.082: E/AndroidRuntime(31326):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
04-01 18:49:50.082: E/AndroidRuntime(31326):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
04-01 18:49:50.082: E/AndroidRuntime(31326):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is line 383 of your AsyncTask in thePlayList (where the null pointer is occurring)

Comment: nice! because I returned null, change it to "none", but still, sometimes its not receiving data - I'm getting cleared list. what can cause it?

Comment: It seems that it has nothing to do with the number of element in the json array. My guess is that any of the element you are retrieving has a missing field and that is causing a nullPointerException, but is hard to say without knowing in which exact line the exception is thrown.

Comment: OK, soo I changed the catch to return the exception, this is what I get when it's not reciving data: JSONException: Value 1 of type java.lang.integer cannot be converted to JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

Use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) instead of an AsyncTask, services are not tied to the lifecycle of your activity or fragment, they have their independent lifecylce, so for example if you create your asynctask inside your activity and the user rotate their device, the AsyncTask would be recreated and it will start over again, instead if you use an IntentService, once the network request has started it doesn't matter if the user changes orientation or switches app, the request will be completed; what you have to do then is find out how to notify your Activites/Fragments that there is new data available, you can use a broadcast, or use an external library such as [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)

Since the json is so big it should be a good idea to store it locally and fetch it only when you know something has changed or when a lot of time has passed

Comment: Can you explain why IntentService a better option?